# query loop "inherit query from template" prevents setting sort order

Tags: wp-query, themes, query, block-editor, sort

I need all auto-generated category pages to sort oldest-to-newest

I'm editing my "All Archives" template in block editor but I'm not having any success

it contains a query loop with "inherit query from template" checked, and turning this off is not an option because it's a template used by all categories and if turned off I won't get the correct content on the correct pages

however, having this option checked also prevents changing the sort order

all the solutions I find online say to edit the theme's `archives.php`, however, this is a file that only exists in legacy themes and I'm using a modern theme

my theme does have an `archives.html` containing the following line:

```
<!-- wp:query {"query":{"perPage":10,"pages":0,"offset":0,"postType":"post","categoryIds":[],"tagIds":[],"order":"desc","orderBy":"date","author":"","search":"","exclude":[],"sticky":"","inherit":true},"tagName":"main"} -->
```

I changed `desc` to `asc`, cleared WP-Optimize cache, cleared Redis cache, cleared Cloudflare cache, restarted PHP-FPM, restarted Apache, restarted MySQL, restarted Redis, then cleared WP-Optimize and Redis caches again, ran a WP-Optimize database cleanup, restarted PHP/Apache/MySQL/Redis again, and then cleared all caches again.  However, there was no change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your detailed description, it seems you've taken several steps to address the issue of sorting your archive pages in WordPress. The fact that changing the "order":"desc" to "asc" in the archives.html file of your theme didn't yield the desired result suggests a deeper issue.

Try this in your functions.php file:

```
function wpb_modify_category_query( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_category() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        // Set the order to ASC
        $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpb_modify_category_query' );
```

Comment: That did the job!  I reverted the archives.html back to its original state.  Thank you very much.